# Twin and Detwin Crystals

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, crystals

Hello i would like to ask  , what are **twin** and **detwin** monocrystals?

what has to do with their crystalographic symmetry?

any consequences ?

any image also would be really helpfull!

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what a twin means crstallographically?

Comment: No i dont , can you tell me where to study? i have basic knowledge of group theory and solid state basics for crystallography

Comment: A twin is a particular crystallographic defect. For example, an fcc crystal is considered to have a particular stacking sequence along the <111> direction. This is usually described as ABCABCABC... where A/B/C correspond to particular placement of one 111 plane above another. Now, a twin is a mis-stacking, resulting in something like ABCABABCABC - a subtle difference, but a planar defect has been introduced. Similarly, bcc and hcp crystals can twin easily.  Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_twinning

Comment: Thanks!!  , And a detwined?

Comment: Detwinned means that a once-twinned crystal has been deformed in such a way as to restore the normal stacking sequence (by, for instance, dislocation glide along the twin plane).